# Automatically post on Facebook wall

Tags: php, facebook

I have used a WordPress plugin to automatically post on Facebook wall all the new posts that are added at my website.

Now we are not using WordPress anymore. Is it possible to have a script that do the same thing - automatically post all my posts to my Facebook wall (I have created a Facebook application)?

I need this information shown:

- photo of the news
- link of the news
- some text of the news

Comment: You could start by looking at the Facebook developer documentation, or the source code of the plugin you were using to see how to write the same functionality in a module for your new CMS/site.

Comment: so there is not ready script to do this ?

Comment: Given that you've not posted what CMS you are using, then I'd imagine it is a custom one. So there probably isn't a script to do this, because how would the script know how to extract details of the posts from your site?

Comment: before i have used wordpress. now we are not using wordpress anymore.

Comment: Right. So if there is a script available that does what you want it to do, how is it going to read items to post from your new website? What are you using now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

"You can create a post on behalf of the user by issuing an HTTP POST request to (http://graph.facebook.com)`/PROFILE_ID/feed` ... with the publish_stream permissions and the following parameters."

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a facebook app that does exactly that : https://apps.facebook.com/extremeplanners

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.